# Lua Roblox gui script?

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a GUI when you sit on a car seat it'll tell you the speed and the value of the car in which it has a "buy" button. I managed to make only the GUI but I can't find the way to script it so when you click buy it teleports the car the player bought to the back of the dealership. Anyway to do it?

(I made a Roblox Car game, scripted to make owner house, built dealerships, maps etc. But I can't find the way to do what I said above)

Thank you.

Comment: You've provided no code at all, how do you expect us to be able to help?

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example, so you'll have to modify it for your game.

```
local car = game.Workspace.Car
local button = script.Parent
local teleportto = game.Workspace.DealerShipCarTeleport

button.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
car:MoveTo(teleportto.Position)
end)
```

It makes use of the MoveTo() function, which sets a model's PrimaryPartCFrame to a Vector3 position. In other words, MoveTo() teleports models to a designated position.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you will need three variables: the `model` for your car, the `button` that when clicked should "buy" the car, and the `destination`, the place where you want the car to spawn (the back of the dealership).

```
local model = game.Workspace.Car --or whatever the path to the model of your car is
local button = script.Parent --or whatever the path to your button is
local destination = Vector3.new(x, y, z) --the 3D coordinates of where you'd like the car to spawn
```

Now that these have been established, we need to make it so that when you click the button, the car will spawned in the spot you want.

First, let's make a function `spawnCar()`that spawns the car at the `destination`.

```
local function spawnCar()
    model:MoveTo(destination) --use this if you want to move the car that's in the dealership
    model:Clone():MoveTo(destination) --use this if you want to make a copy of the car and move that
end
```

Here, you have two options. The first option just moves the car that was already in the dealership, but the second option first makes a copy of the car and then moves *that* to the back of the dealership.

Both options use the `MoveTo()` method of the car's Model. All Models have this method available. To learn more, check out the [ROBLOX Wiki's page on it](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Model/MoveTo).

The second option makes use of the `Clone()` method of the car's Model. All Models and many other object types including Parts have this method available. To learn more, check out the [ROBLOX Wiki's page on it](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Instance/Clone).

Now, we will write code that "listens" for the user to click on the button. Look at the following method:

```
button.MouseButton1Down:connect(func)
```

If we add this to our code, every time the button is clicked, whatever function we pass in for `func` will be executed. If you'd like to learn more about `MouseButton1Down` and other similar properties, I highly recommend taking a look at the [ROBLOX Wiki](http://wiki.roblox.com/); it has extensive documentation on these. You can find `MouseButton1Down` [here](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/GuiButton/MouseButton1Down).

Now, to put this all together, we will pass our `spawnCar()` function into the click listener.

```
button.MouseButton1Down:connect(spawnCar) --notice it's "spawnCar", NOT "spawnCar()"
```

And we're done! Here's what the final code will look like:

```
local model = game.Workspace.Car --or whatever the path to the model of your car is
local button = script.Parent --or whatever the path to your button is
local destination = Vector3.new(x, y, z) --the 3D coordinates of where you'd like the car to spawn

local function spawnCar()
    model:MoveTo(destination) --use this if you want to move the car that's in the dealership
    model:Clone():MoveTo(destination) --use this if you want to make a copy of the car and move that
end

button.MouseButton1Down:connect(spawnCar) --notice it's "spawnCar", NOT "spawnCar()"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Model/MoveTo) is what you are looking for. What you need to do is re-set the posisition of your parts or model on the event of clicking your button. Here is an example of a script you can insert in your button: `script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:connect(function() Model:MoveTo ( Vector3 position ) end)`. Here are some more links that I think could help you:

 - https://scriptinghelpers.org/questions/9837/how-do-i-position-a-model

 - http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/GuiButton/MouseButton1Click

Answer (score 0):

Try using CFrame to teleport the car

**Example**:

```lua
local car = workspace.Car -- define the car.
local tp = workspace.TP -- Like a position of where it should be, must be anchored at all -- times!!!!

car.CFrame = CFrame.new(tp.Position) -- Position of where you want it to be.
```

The above code sets 2 variables, one the car and another the tp part. Then we set the car CFrame to the tp's position property. Hope i helped you!